# issuse on installing application on Android

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have a problem on installing an application on Android. when I click run, it shows the error below. I have installed the driver and enable the usb debugging.
Could someone help me. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have enough space on your Android Device for the application to fit on? Try removing some applications or unneeded files.

Comment: I have removed some application already, but still have same error

Comment: restart eclipse and device and try to clean and rebuild your project after uninstalling some apps

Comment: It's space problem...Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it all sorted out! :)

Answer (score 2):

This error come if your device do not have enough space for app. So you need to UN-install some app from device( or free some memory in device ) and also check your app storage location on manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

This is Because in your Device there is Much application which keeps more memory and much heavy application also.... So you have to un-install some of them application and also clear cache data of that application from your Device...So you will get some of memory and run your app on Device.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have enough Internal memory, You can move the application to the SD Card. 
If there is enough Internal memory, then try uninstalling applications which are not needed and removing the unwanted cache.
Then restart your phone and install the application.